# Fit indices in structural equation modelling

Tags: multiple-regression, model, structural-equation-modeling, fitting

How to improve the model fit in structural equation modelling. I have run my model without taking into account the covariances among mediating variables and my chi-square value was 0.00. But when I used the covariance between the exogenous variables (mediating variables) on the basis of fit indices my model fit or chi-square value increased substantially. Is this a right way to improve your model fit?

Comment: If your chi-square value was 0 zero, you have a saturated model. Do you mean your p-value?